# ActionScript recursive loop by return statement

Tags: apache-flex, recursion, return

I'm having the recursion loop of which should return value if it's found at some nested level in ArrayCollection. Once return value is found and returned by function but in next iteration return value becomes back to null. What I'm missing or doing wrong?

```
// calling function
...
foundedItem = this.recursiveFindFunction(valueList); 
...

private function recursiveFindFunction(items:ArrayCollection):Object
{
    var retVal:Object;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        var value:Object = items.getItemAt(i);
        if (value.name == this.attribute.value.directValue as String)
        {
            retVal = value;
            break;
        }

        if (value.hasOwnProperty("children"))
        {
                this.recursiveFindFunction(value.children);
        }   
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not catching the return of the recursive call anywhere

You are not checking the return value here

```
 if (value.hasOwnProperty("children"))
    {
            this.recursiveFindFunction(value.children);
    }
```

A possible fix would be adding a return statement as such:

```
 if (value.hasOwnProperty("children"))
    {
            return this.recursiveFindFunction(value.children);
    }
```

(notice the return)

Comment: @FinFlex what ended up being the issue?

Comment: This is so old i can't remember how this ended up.